# javascript separating document.getElementById for reusability

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign value to isSelected based on condition below. It worked fine beofre refactoring. It is failing once i refactored. What may be my mistake

**Working Code**

```
    var isSelected= false;
    var temp = isSelected?(document.getElementById("Link").disabled = false): 
(document.getElementById("Link").disabled = true);
```

**Refactored code (Not working)**

```
var isSelected= false;
var myLink = document.getElementById("Link").disabled;
var temp = isSelected?(myLink = false): (myLink = true);
```

Comment: What is failing, the link not being disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `disabled` property is a primitive, when you assign it to a variable, you assign the actual value, and not the reference to the property.

Instead cache the reference to the element that was returned from `document.getElementById()`:

```
var isSelected= false;
var myLink = document.getElementById("Link");
myLink.disabled = !isSelected;
```

Comment: IMO, should be refactored semantically so it is readable: `myLink.disabled = !isSelected`